# Too many queries to the database in Wordpress/Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have had a problem with a lot of database queries for three days now. When I log in as admin and, for example, just deactivate a plugin or make a small change via Elementor on the page, a lot of queries start to be pumped into the database. I already disabled all plugins and also the theme, but it didn't help. I always get this message in the debugger: User '******' has exceeded the 'max_updates_per_hour' resource (current value: 2300).

Then it happens that I can't even log in to wp-admin, because the queries use up all the capacity. Query monitor show about 500 queries to database.

How would I be able to identify what is making these queries to my database and flooding it? Is there any SQL command for this?

I turn off all plugins, theme. Still same problem.

Comment: Few ways to start troubleshooting: sql's: `show full processlist;` , log queries, tcpdump for connection requests and identifying sources..

Comment: To my understanding, 2300 is a low value for MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR - which is a PHP system setting. You may need to discuss raising it with your host or system administrator.